# Jenkins spawn infinite number of processes during "Execute shell" step

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I have issue with running "Execute shell" from Jenkins. It's spawn infinite number of subprocesses (like /tmp/hudson173860205520658648.sh) that eat all memory. No matter what inside: even script with simple 'ls' command spawns infinitely.  All other steps except "Execute shell" seems to be OK.

Jenkins version is 1.544

```
user@jenkins# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue. Not sure what caused it. I've tried reinstalling plugins, downgrading jenkins, etc but with no luck.

Only [removing jenkins](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/j/jenkins/uninstall.html) and fresh install resolved issue.

Comment: Yes, only thing that helps me was restored backup :)